# Navigation bar in html5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a quick question. I'm wondering if it is possible to have a external html file with my navigation bar in it and have that be put in to all of my pages for my website. If so how do I do this? I have tried using these methods:

```
<script rel="import" src="navigation-bar.html"></script>

$("#nav-bar").load("navigation-bar.html")
```

but so far neither of them have worked... Do I have to use PHP and if I do how do I implement this.

please help.

Comment: in php just use `include` or `require`

Comment: what would the file syntax look like... I have never used php @nogad

Comment: `include('file.html');`

Comment: `<script rel="import" src="navigation-bar.html">` - `.html` files are not considered as scripts. Plus, the `</script>` isn't needed. You probably meant to use `<link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">` as an example. Example taken from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: PHP isn't really needed if you want to include files. If you're not going to use PHP or for db work, then don't use it. You can include files a few other ways. One of which is an SSI `.shtml` method that I've used for years and still do to this day.

Comment: i will be using php for a db so is it best to use it? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yes it is best to use PHP when coding in conjunction with a database. However, you can run `.html` files as PHP also. It's an option. I run that sometimes also when I don't want or can't start renaming a whole bunch of `.php` extensions.

Comment: You've quite a few answers below. A few are good but the ones about jQuery/Javascript shouldn't be used. If someone disables javascript, then you're back to "square one" and having to use a serverside method. I don't know if you want me to submit my own answer, that's up to you. I'm kind of on the sidelines on this one. I'd go "serverside" all the way with this. You can include `.html` files though when running `.php` files or as I already stated above about running `.html` files as PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use PHP to do this.

Here is the structure of how it would work.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <?php require('/directory/to/your/header.php'); ?>
 </head>
 <body>
   ...Your Content Here
 </body>
 </html>
```

In a separate header.php file you would include your navbar.

Header.php

```
 <?php 
   echo '...enter your Navbar HTML code';
 ?>
```

Your file will have to have the extension .php and every time you write in php, you must start and end with

```
 <?php 
    ...enter your php code...
 ?>
```

You can mix php with html simply by writing the php into the HTML. Take for example the following href:

```
 <a href = "<?php echo 'www.yourlinkhere.com'?>">Your link Name</a>
```

For more information please refer to :
 http://php.net/manual/en/

Comment: *"and every time you write in php, you must start and end with"* - Not always required. That's only if there's pure HTML (or JS) below PHP, only then do you need to close it off with `?>`. *"Your file will have to have the extension .php"* - Again, not always true. One can instruct their system to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: Hi Fred, you are correct. if the code simple has PHP, you do not need to close the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

put:

```
include("navigation-bar.html")
```

on top of your code.

This way you won't have to write the same navigation code in each webpage that you are going to host.

OR

you can try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="h1.html"></div> 
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Read more at: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: What if someone disables JS?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest solution that should work even in user agents without scripting support.

For example, your page will look like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <iframe src="navbar.html" class="navbar" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: extra http request, css issues .. bad idea